# Does getDay() comply with ISO 8601?

Tags: javascript

I'm having real trouble working out whether JavaScript's `getDay()` method (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) complies with ISO 8601.

`getDay()` returns `0` for Sunday, `1` for Monday etc..

The documentation recommends mapping to day names like this:

```
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
...
var n = weekday[(new Date()).getDay()];
```

I can only see that the ISO standard defines Monday as the first day of the week. I would assume this means Monday should be 0, not Sunday.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Can you clarify and would you recommend overriding the method to make Monday the first day of the week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the weekdays are represented only matters if you want to use a date format where the weekday actually is represented as a number, e.g. the `YYYY-Www-D` format, or if you want to get the week number for a specific date.

Otherwise it doesn't matter how the weekdays are represented numerically. A monday is still a monday.

Comment: Isn't there a standard though? I'm creating a public API that uses ISO Week Year, ISO Week and ISO Day Number. I want to make sure I implement both sides properly and if there's a standard I want to comply with it in all parts of my app.

Comment: @JonnyH: Yes, if you want the week day represented as a number according to the ISO8601 format, then you have to convert the Javascript weekday number using `(theDate.getDay() + 6) % 7 + 1` to make the sunday 7 instead of 0.

Comment: This looks like the definitive answer to the question, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Monday";
weekday[1]="Tuesday";
weekday[2]="Wednesday";
...
var n = weekday[((new Date()).getDay() + 6) % 7 + 1];
```

or extend the Date prototype:

```
Date.prototype.getISODay = function(){ return (this.getDay() + 6) % 7 + 1; }
```

and then use

```
var n = weekday[(new Date()).getISODay()];
```

Comment: this is a good concept, but this answer contains incorrect day numbering. according to ISO 8601, Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7.

Answer (score 2):

The only sources I could find which state which numbers the days of the week should be were [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) and [this page](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html). Both suggest the day of week numbers should be `1` to `7` and start from *Monday*.

I support [ic3b3rg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/753237/ic3b3rg)'s suggestion of extending [`Date.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype), although would suggest using UTC and a literal to get the names. The following example uses an *Object* and an anonymous function so the names only need be defined once.

```
(function () {
    var dayNames = {1: 'Monday', 2: 'Tuesday', 3: 'Wednesday', 4: 'Thursday', 5: 'Friday', 6: 'Saturday', 7: 'Sunday'};
    // Local time
    Date.prototype.getISODay = function () {return this.getDay() || 7;};
    Date.prototype.getISODayName = function () {return dayNames[this.getDay() || 7];};
    // Date.prototype.getDayName = Date.prototype.getISODayName
    // UTC
    Date.prototype.getUTCISODay = function () {return this.getUTCDay() || 7;};
    Date.prototype.getUTCISODayName = function () {return dayNames[this.getUTCDay() || 7];};
    // Date.prototype.getUTCDayName = Date.prototype.getUTCISODayName;
}());
```

As the day name would be the same as the ISO day name (assuming *English*), I've added in extra lines which can be uncommented if you want both.